# How can I add a new custom standard value token for sitecore branch templates?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore8

Sitecore comes with several standard custom value tokens when creating branch templates (i.e. `$name` for the name of the new item, `$parentid`, for the id of the parent).

Is there anyway to add new variables?

Specifically I want a variable that will allow me to access the items path when added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a sitecore blog post for this [ADD CUSTOM STANDARD VALUES TOKENS IN THE SITECORE ASP.NET CMS](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/add-custom-standard-values-tokens-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms) but TBH, **it's wrong** . I'm not sure why sitecore insist on producing "*untested prototype(s)*" all the time in these posts. The guy in that blog literally says *You can implement a solution based on the following **untested prototype*** o_O

---

For some reason sitecore are jumping though various hoops to decompile the source and then recreate it (give a man a hammer and everything looks like a nail maybe?). This makes your code very fragile should the default behaviour change and is just totally unnecessary.

You can add a new variable in a few lines of code:

```
public class NewVariablesReplacer : MasterVariablesReplacer
{
    public override string Replace(string text, Item targetItem)
    {
        //still need to assert these here
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(text, "text");
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(targetItem, "targetItem");
        string tempTxt = text;


        if (text.Contains("$path"))
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(targetItem.Paths, "targetItem.Paths");
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(targetItem.Paths.FullPath, "targetItem.Paths.FullPath");
            tempTxt = text.Replace("$path", targetItem.Paths.FullPath);
        }
        
        //Do what you would normally do.
        return base.Replace(tempTxt, targetItem);
    }
}
```

This works without decompiling because it retains the base functionality by calling `base.Replace(text, targetItem);`.

You then need to alter the default behaviour in the xml as in the blog post:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="MasterVariablesReplacer">
        <patch:attribute name="value">Sitecore.Sharedsource.Data.NewVariablesReplacer ,Sitecore.Sharedsource</patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Only suggestion I'd offer is not conditionally calling base.Replace(), but making sure it always get called. If the field contains tokens in addition to $path, only $path will get replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, we have these variables at our disposal:

```
$name: The item name
$id: The item ID
$parentid: The item ID of the parent item
$parentname: The item name of the parent item
$date: The system date
$time: The system time
$now: The combination of system date and time
```

Tokens are variables that start with the “$” symbol. When a content item is created in the content tree, the pipeline that gets invoked is:

```
<expandInitialFieldValue help="Processors should derive from Sitecore.Pipelines.ExpandInitialFieldValue.ExpandInitialFieldValueProcessor">
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.ExpandInitialFieldValue.SkipStandardValueItems, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.ExpandInitialFieldValue.CheckSharedField, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.ExpandInitialFieldValue.ReplaceVariables, Sitecore.Kernel" /></expandInitialFieldValue>
```

The pipeline that does all the work is:

```
public override void Process(ExpandInitialFieldValueArgs args)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");
  MasterVariablesReplacer variablesReplacer = Factory.GetMasterVariablesReplacer();
  string text = args.SourceField.Value;
  if (variablesReplacer == null)
    args.Result = text;
  else
    args.Result = variablesReplacer.Replace(text, args.TargetItem);
 }
```

In the ReplaceVariables processor, you will see that there is a call to another class that does all the work. This class is defined in the section of web.config.

```
<setting name="MasterVariablesReplacer" value="Sitecore.Data.MasterVariablesReplacer,Sitecore.Kernel.dll" />
```

Decompile this class and you will see that the execution order is Replace > ReplaceValues > ReplaceWithDefault with Replace being a virtual method while the others are not. Fortunately for us, this means we can easily override the combined logic with a custom subclass of our own.

```
<!--<setting name="MasterVariablesReplacer" value="Sitecore.Data.MasterVariablesReplacer,Sitecore.Kernel.dll" />-->
<setting name="MasterVariablesReplacer" value="Client.SitecoreUtil.SettingsOverrides.MasterVariablesReplacer,Client.Sitecore" />
```

In our custom class, we have to override the Replace method with the same or similar code. Then we need two local private versions of ReplaceValues and ReplaceWithDefault. We can use the same or similar code for ReplaceWithDefault but the ReplaceValues method is where you would define your custom tokens and also tell Sitecore what to do with it. For example, let’s say you want to replace the custom “$test” token with the string “hello” this would be the resulting code.

```
private string ReplaceValues(string text, Func<string> defaultName, Func<string> defaultId, Func<string> defaultParentName, Func<string> defaultParentId)
{
        if (text.Length == 0 || text.IndexOf('$') < 0)
            return text;
        ReplacerContext context = this.GetContext();
        if (context != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in (SafeDictionary<string, string>)context.Values)
                text = text.Replace(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
        }
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$name", defaultName, context);
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$id", defaultId, context);
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$parentid", defaultParentId, context);
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$parentname", defaultParentName, context);
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$date", (Func<string>)(() => DateUtil.IsoNowDate), context);
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$time", (Func<string>)(() => DateUtil.IsoNowTime), context);
        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$now", (Func<string>)(() => DateUtil.IsoNow), context);

        text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$test", (Func<string>)(() => "hello"), context);

        return text;
}
```

That is all there is to define custom token variables for Sitecore standard values. All the work is done in the ReplaceValues method.

Comment: *we **have to** override the Replace method with the same or similar code*. you don't have to override it, it's a virtual method, not an abstract method. You can add functionality without replacing it entirely. `public virtual string Replace(string text, Item targetItem);`. This appears to be the same solution as detailed in the blog post, which I believe to be ill informed

Comment: Yes it's virtual so by definition we don't have to override but we have to override to accomplish our mission and cannot use out of the box.  Hope this clarifies.